# How to query files by metadata in GCS?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In Google cloud Storage (GCS) you can associate [metadata](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata) with each object(file).
I am trying to query files with certain metadata.
But I can't find any methods to do so. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to query by metadata - you can retrieve the metadata for a particular object by performing an HTTP HEAD on the object.

Mike Schwartz, Google Cloud Storage team

Comment: Thanks Mike. I was going to use metadata to enable tagging for objects. But since I can't query for them, I don't see another alternative than creating a tag bearing entity for every GCS object in the AppengineDataStore. Pity, it would be so nice otherwise. Or maybe you could suggest something better?

Comment: @husayt you could store a reverse index from tag to object in the appengine datastore. if you use memcache for caching, it should be pretty efficient