# how to get files from Cloud Storage for Firebase that created at a certain time?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

[image]

I need to delete images at `eventPoster` folder in my cloud storage that has last modified metadata more than 6 months ago.

so I want to make a cron job using Cloud Function, and I need to 'query' that files that has last modified more than 6 months ago

how to do that using Admin SDK?

Answer (score 2):

I think I find the solution

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17640298/9605341), There is no way to query by metadata

so, as for now I use the code below to get out of date files

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as moment from "moment";

const app = admin.initializeApp(); // I am using Google Cloud Function, much more simple to initialize the app
const bucket = app.storage().bucket();

const response = await bucket.getFiles({prefix: "eventPoster/"}); // set your folder name in prefix here
const files = response[0];

const sixMonthAgo = moment().subtract(6, "months").toDate();
const outOfDateFiles = files.filter((file) => {
    const createdTime = new Date(file.metadata.timeCreated);
    return moment(createdTime).isBefore(sixMonthAgo);
});

console.log(`number of outdated files: ${outOfDateFiles.length}`);
```

read the [documentation in here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) for further reading